# QueryDsl - issue with mapping query with case builder inside aggregates

Tags: sql, hibernate, querydsl

I have a problem constructing a query which uses cases inside aggregates.

My setup: QueryDsl 3.3.2, JPA + Hibernate 3.6.10.Final

I Have two entities (psudo code):

```
Car {
    private String ownerNumber;
    private String color;
}

Client {
    private String number;
}
```

There is no direct relationship between those two, just for some reporting simplicity Car holds Client number reference.

The first problem:
As I found on different SO posts I cannot use join on this etities using custom properties, I need to use for example cross join. Using: from client cl, car.c where cl.number=c.owner_number - the drawback is I'm not able to get all clients (which indicates lack of a car) - just thos that have connection for those two props. This is not too good for my reports but let's say I can live with that.

The second problem:
In the same query I also need to aggregate some data - I need to count all user cars, and let say all red. So I need sth like this:

```
SELECT c.number, count(c.id) AS total, SUM(CASE WHEN c.color='RED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as allRed FROM client cl, car c WHERE cl.number=c.ownerNumber GROUP BY c.number;
```

This query works as expected;
For QueryDsl I have:

```
QClient client = Qclient.client;
QCar car = Qcar.car;

NumberExpression<Integer> redCarExp = new CaseBuilder()
            .when(car.color.eq("RED"))
            .then(1)
            .otherwise(0);


List<Tuple> list = new JPAQuery(em)
    .from(client, car)
    .where(client.number.eq(car.ownerNumber))
    .groupBy(client.number)
    .list(client.number, car.id.count(), redCarExp.sum());
```

Running this generates JPAQuery shown below and exception. Without the last sum() part all works ok. I'm not sure where is the issue here.

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.ParameterNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SelectExpression
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.CaseNode.getFirstThenNode(CaseNode.java:44)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.CaseNode.getDataType(CaseNode.java:40)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findFunctionReturnType(SessionFactoryHelper.java:402)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.AggregateNode.getDataType(AggregateNode.java:82)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:154)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:857)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:645)
    org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:685)
    org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:244)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:256)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:138)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
    org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1770)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:277)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:342)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:262)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:129)
    com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:97)
    com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.list(AbstractJPAQuery.java:242)
    com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.list(AbstractJPAQuery.java:236)

Comment: Might be related to this issue https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/185

Comment: Right, `Expressions.numberTemplate(Long, "1")` did the trick - thanks!   Is there any way to join this two entities by custom prop in querydsl?

Comment: The where based join is the way to go in JPQL

Comment: @TimoWestkämper - Is there any way - using where base join or other technique, to also get rows from entities without connection (like in left join) and to indicate lack of car? this is really required now in my reports so I need to think about redesigning it somehow